# replace fragments in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I want a ViewPager with a FragmentStatePagerAdapter that instead of using one fragment use a pair of fragments for viewpager, for example:  A1 A2 ; B1 B2 ; C1 C2 ; D1 D2  ....
when activity starts viewpager use first fragment to display and when user click on that fragment(or a button) first fragment is replaced with second fragment an if again click second fragment is replaced by first fragment in fact by clicking viewpager pages switch between fragments.(i wanna create a flashcard app, and if you know better way to this please tell me)
i have no idea how to create such a thing, i need your help , thank you!

Comment: Have you think about using View/Component instead?

Comment: i am new in android developmet,how to use "View/Component"?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html

Comment: thank you!,  you mean i create a custom Component for a single card and list all them in a ViewPager?

Comment: You are probably going to have some new ideas when you finished understand how to work with a component.